# Передача выборки из SQL в ORM

Tags: php, sql, orm

Я делаю выборку нативным sql(так как там вложенный запрос на сумму полей),но надо передать полученные данные в "формат" ORM.как это осуществить?

Comment: какую ОRM Вы используете?

Comment: используется kohana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

описание работы ORM в Kohana на русском

> http://kohana3.ru/orm/

в данный момент не лучший выбор из существующих вариантов, если есть возможность я бы выбрал что-то другое